# How to use docusign in my Android app and users don't need to log in

Tags: docusignapi

I need to use docusign in the app to let the user sign the contract, but I found that the REST api using docusign requires authorization, and the authorization requires the user to log in to their docusign account.

Is there another way for users to authorize and sign without logging in?

Comment: If you use DocuSign's [JWT authentication flow](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) you only need to do a ONE-TIME authorization through a browser to grant consent to your application, then after that users of the integration will not need to log in to use DocuSign functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to **send** an envelope (transaction), an access token is needed. But not for signing. There are several workflows available to you and your app:

1. Use a [Powerform](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-using-powerforms). In this use case, a DocuSign user creates the template for the envelope and turns it into a powerform. Now, anyone with the url (including your Android app) can cause an envelope to be created automatically and then start the signing process. No access token needed by the signer!
2. Use a server-side process to create the envelope, including any customization needed. Since the server process is operating on its own, it'd use JWT authentication to obtain an access token for creating the envelope. It'd also create the signing ceremony url from DocuSign. Your Android app would then open the signing ceremony url to let the app user sign the document(s). No access token is needed by the Android app.
3. Your Android app could obtain a DocuSign access token from its server. Then your Android app could directly use the DocuSign API to create an embedded signing url for the app user to use. The access token would represent the app, not the person signing on your app.

### Code examples

- [JWT authentication code examples](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-01&type=&language=)
- [Embedded signing examples](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-03&type=&language=): see example eg001 source from any of the repos.